# xdotool, ctrl key and keyboard layouts

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xdotool

**Problem**

I use `xdotool keydown Control` and `xdotool keyup Control` from my  application to emulate Ctrl presses. When layout is set to `us`, everything works, but when layout changes to something else (`fr` or `ru`), applications stop seeing the ctrl events.

**Question**

Why is that happening? What can I do to make ctrl key manipulation work uniformly across layouts?

**Some info**

Command that I use to setup layouts:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,fr -option -option "grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,ctrl:nocaps"
```

Output from xev with `us` layout:

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x5c, subw 0x0, time 11278564, (317,709), root:(1279,736),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x5c, subw 0x0, time 11278676, (317,709), root:(1279,736),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output from xev with `fr` layout:

```
KeyPress event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x5c, subw 0x0, time 11343218, (312,520), root:(1274,547),
    state 0x2010, keycode 8 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 109, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 116, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

KeyRelease event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x5c, subw 0x0, time 11343460, (312,520), root:(1274,547),
    state 0x2010, keycode 8 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 123, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 1
```

Verbose output from setxkbmap:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,fr
options:    grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,ctrl:nocaps
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+fr:2+inet(evdev)+group(lctrl_lshift_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
  xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)"   };
  xkb_types     { include "complete"    };
  xkb_compat    { include "complete"    };
  xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+fr:2+inet(evdev)+group(lctrl_lshift_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)"  };
  xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"   };
};
```

xmodmap output for control:

```
$  xmodmap -pme | grep -i control
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
$  xmodmap -pke | grep -i control
keycode  37 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L
keycode  66 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your `xev` output, when in the *us* mode the Control_L
key down is equivalent to keycode 37 with the state moving from 0x10 to
0x14, whereas in the *fr* mode you have keycode 8 and state 0x2010 not
changing, and several MappingNotify events.

The *state* is a bitmap of which modifiers are currently applied, eg shift,
control, alt and so on. They can be shown with

```
xmodmap -pme
```

which for example for me (on a completely different keyboard setup) is currently

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Meta_R (0x86)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4      
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

These list the 8 bit positions in *state*, with:

1. shift   = bit 0 (state 0x1),
2. lock    = bit 1 (state 0x2),
3. control = bit 2 (state 0x4), etc.

Your state 0x2010 includes a value 0x2000 beyond these 8 bits, which is how the 2 keymaps in one is implemented, and shows when you are in fr mode.

If we look at how `xdotool` works, when you are in the 2nd key mapping as shown by state 0x2000, it looks up Control_L to find the keycode, then looks up the keycode in the `xmodmap -pke` columns for the current state, and doesnt find Control_L.  So it takes a spare keycode 8, and temporarily changes the mapping so keycode 8 = keysym Control_L, and then sends that key event. Unfortunately, this keycode is not in the modifier mapping for the control bit.

---

So perhaps what will work is if you change the mapping you have for keycode 37 so that all the columns have Control_L. I dont know how many columns you have, but do `xmodmap -pke | grep 'keycode 37'` and count them, then change them all eg:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 37 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L'
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, `xdotool key` can take keycode decimal numbers instead of keysym arguments. This isn't mentioned in the man pages.

Comment: I already have 'keycode  66 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L' in my setup, so by that reasoning it should be able to find Control_L in the mapping?

Comment: Changing 37 to all Control_L's doesn't change this either.

Comment: @Rogach could you add the output of `xmodmap -pme|grep control` and `xmodmap -pke|grep Control` to your original post?

Comment: Sure, added in the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Rogach In your xev output, the original state is 0x2010, so you must have another modifier down, so perhaps 4 columns arent enough. try 6 or 8?

Comment: `xmodmap -e` ignores all other columns (still get 4 in the output of xmodmap -e). I'm currently trying to send 37th keycode directly using xdotool c library, but not much success yet.

Comment: @Rogach you can use xdotool to send the keycode, just  use the decimal number instead of a keysym. `xdotool key 37`.

Comment: Sending keycode directly works. Great! I should have read documentation more thoroughly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont think using a keycode is mentioned in the man page. I saw it in the sources.